# Rails application is requesting to a non-existed precompiled asset in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I precompile assets locally by running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and commit them to my git repo. After deploying it to production server using Capistrano, I just realized that some assets are missing, but some other assets are found and okay.

I open my browser, and view the page source. It seems that my application is requesting to an asset that is not exists in server, like so:

```
http://mywebsite.com/assets/users-97ff9cd1fc91c7ec829ef21dac3540b1.css
```

*The URL above causing Firebug to show **NetworkError: 404 Not Found***

whereas, in my **'public/assets'** path (where the precompiled assets are generated), the file named `users-97ff9cd1fc91c7ec829ef21dac3540b1.css` 
is not exists.

In my **manifest.yml**, the **users.css** file is actually pointed to a file named 
`users-807c131fa112764e83fdbcd416b3f3fa.css`
which is exists in server. So the request should be appointed to this file.

**manifest.yml**

```
...    
users.css: users-807c131fa112764e83fdbcd416b3f3fa.css
...
```

As you might guess, the URL should be addressed to that existed file:

`http://mywebsite.com/assets/users-807c131fa112764e83fdbcd416b3f3fa.css`

How to correct this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is down to [`asset fingerprinting`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark), and is a standard feature of Rails

---

**Asset Fingerprinting**

> Fingerprinting is a technique that makes the name of a file dependent
>   on the contents of the file. When the file contents change, the
>   filename is also changed. For content that is static or infrequently
>   changed, this provides an easy way to tell whether two versions of a
>   file are identical, even across different servers or deployment dates

This basically means every asset in your pipeline will have a hashed key appended to it, to ensure uniqueness

To accommodate this, you need to dynamically reference assets in your pipeline, with technology such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

---

**Dynamic Referencing**

The good news is that `.css` and `.js` are all accessed automatically by Rails after pre-compilation, however, if you're referencing specific asset files (such as images), you'll have to reference them dynamically

Here's what I mean:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/users.css
.hello {
    background: url("google-home.png"); /* - doesn't work with precompiling, as references static object */
}

#app/assets/stylesheets/users.css.scss
.hello {
    background: image_url("google-home.png"); /* - dynamic reference using one of the SASS Rails Helpers */
}
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Good luck finding the solution then :)

Comment: hi medBo! Answering questions help me get better at Rails, so I try to spend at least a few hours a day answering!

Answer (score 0):

When an application is deployed with capistrano ( and when capistrano precompiled assets on production server ) **shared/assets** directory is symlinked to **public/assets** and all released versions can access to application's assets.

In this case you repository contains a public/assets directory. 
Have you a shared/assets directory on your production server ?
Can you see **users-97ff9cd1fc91c7ec829ef21dac3540b1.css**  file on a old release version?

I presume you have a good reason to precompile your assets localy, so you can try another solution like :

- Precompile localy your assets when you deploy and rsync assets with
  your production server. This solution is described here :
  http://sandeli.us/precompile-assets-locally-with-capistrano/

Or

- Cleanup your assets before precompile :

  `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile`

Hope this help.